# How to remove the extra comma from this python code

Tags: python

This is my python code thats giving me a extra comma at the end and I am unable to figure out how to solve this issue.

Code:

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())
print("[",end="")
for i in range(0,x+1):
    for j in range(0,y+1):
        for k in range(0,z+1):
            if((i+j+k)!=n):
                print("[",end="")
                print(i,end=",")
                print(j,end=",")
                print(k,end="")
                print("]",end="")
                print("",end=",")
print("]",end="")
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5PVF.png)

Comment: you might want to look into itertools permutations, as that seems like your goal

Comment: Please show your output as copied-and-pasted text, formatted as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`append` func is used to collect

```
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())
a =  []
# print("[",end="")
for i in range(0,x+1):
    for j in range(0,y+1):
        for k in range(0,z+1):
            if((i+j+k)!=n):
                a.append([i,j,k])
print(a)
```

Comment: Take x as input also, then it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.join#str.join) method:

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())

print("[", end="")
join_list = []
for i in range(0, x + 1):
    for j in range(0, y + 1):
        for k in range(0, z + 1):
            if (i + j + k) != n:
                join_list.append(f"[{i},{j},{k}]")
print(",".join(join_list), end="")
print("]", end="")
```

Or in combination with [comprehesions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions):

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())

print(
    "["
    + ",".join(
        f"[{i},{j},{k}]"
        for i in range(x + 1) for j in range(y + 1) for k in range(z + 1)
        if i + j + k != n
    )
    + "]",
    end=""
)
```

Or use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools.product#itertools.product) instead of the nested comprehensions:

```
from itertools import product

x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())

print(
    "["
    + ",".join(
        "[{},{},{}]".format(*p)
        for p in product(range(x + 1), range(y + 1), range(z + 1))
        if sum(p) != n
    )
    + "]",
    end=""
)
```

Or build the list first, then convert it to string and replace the blanks:

```
from itertools import product

x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())

result = [
    list(p)
    for p in product(range(x + 1), range(y + 1), range(z + 1))
    if sum(p) != n
]
print(str(result).replace(" ", ""), end="")
```